# nested loop with jQuery eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < Count; i++) {

            $('td').eq(i).prepend($('th').eq(???).text() + '<br />');
}
```

I will always want the `td` element at index `i`, however I only want to prepend the `th` element that is at index 0, 1, or 2.

Example:
         prepend th 0 to td 0
         prepend th 1 to td 1
         prepend th 2 to td 2
         prepend th 0 to td 3
         prepend th 1 to td 4
         prepend th 2 to td 5

How can I perform this loop inside of my eq()? Is eq() the correct method to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `$('th').eq(i)` should do what you want. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, `i` goes higher than index 2 so it doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that part of it. Use `i % 3` to reduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate over `th` using **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method then get all corresponding `td` using the index with help of **[`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** and prepend the content.

```
// iterate over th
$('th').each(function(i){
  // get td elements in same column using index
  $('td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').prepend($(this).text() + '<br/>');
});
```

---

With your own for loop generate the index by taking modulus and update.

```
// cache the th and td
var $th = $('th'),
      $td=$('td'),
      // store counts of th
      c = $th.length;

// iterate over th
for (i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
   // update wuth corresponding th text
   // where `i % c` refers to the index
   $td.eq(i).prepend($th.eq(i % c).text() + '<br />');
}
```

---

Or much simpler way with for loop(same logic as in the first method).

```
var $th = $('th'),
      c = $th.length;

for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
   $('td:nth-child(' + i + ')').prepend($th.eq(i).text() + '<br />');
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The first method there works great.

Comment: @noclist : glad to help :)